# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'render' in streamlit web-rtc

Tags: python, webrtc, streamlit, yolov8

Need help with outputting real-time segmentation with streamlit web-rtc using the YOLOv8 model.

Here's what I have tried:

```
import streamlit as st
import av
import numpy as np
from streamlit_webrtc import webrtc_streamer
from ultralytics import YOLO

model = YOLO('yolov8n.pt')

def video_frame_callback(frame):
    img = frame.to_ndarray(format="bgr24")

    results = model.predict(img)
    result_plot = results[0].plot()
    output_img = np.squeeze(result_plot.render())

    return av.VideoFrame.from_ndarray(output_img, format="bgr24"), results


webrtc_streamer(key="example", video_frame_callback=video_frame_callback)
```

However, while the stream opens up, there's no prediction being made and I retrieve this error:

> AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'render'

Would appreciate assistance